# SQL Inner Join Returns WAY More Rows Than Expected

Tags: sql, inner-join

The following query returns >7000 rows when each table only has 340 rows.

```
SELECT Config.Spec, TempTable.Spec FROM Confg INNER JOIN TempTable on Config.Spec = TempTable.Spec
```

Why would this happen?  If an INNER JOIN only returns a row if there is a match in both tables then why would it return multiple rows for a match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is more than one row with the same `Spec` value in `TempTable` for the same `Spec` value in `Confg`, then you will get duplicate rows, and vice versa.

Comment: This is the answer but I wish I understood why SQL behaves this way.  If I also SELECT Config.uid I still get the multiple rows -- I think really what I am looking for is a SELECT DISTINCT LEFT JOIN.  Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @Jim: it behaves this way because it is a set-based language and this proved to be the most useful behaviour. If it did not work this way, how could you, e.g., join `Category` and `Product` tables to find all the Products in a Category? You would propose that only one row ever be returned on a match?

Comment: As I am not a computer scientist I am in no position to propose anything :).  Thanks for the insight though, this now makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Are the Spec field values non unique? This might explain why the query returns too many results; with duplicates you get get an effective cross product for those.